# input three integers and ascending,type "yes" keep program going and if type "no" end the program

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> Write a program that input 3 integers from user and then sort these numbers in ascending order. When it finishes the sorting, the program asks whether user want do another sorting. The answer will be ‘yes’ or ‘no’.

An example of desired output of the program would be:

1. Enter three integers:    30, 4, 1
2. The ascending order is   1, 4, 30
3. Do you want to do another sorting (yes/no)  :  yes
4. Enter three integers    :    30, 4, 8  
5. The ascending order is   4, 8, 30
6. Do you want to do another sorting (yes/no)  :  yes
7. Enter three integers    :    3, 16, 7  
8. The ascending order is   3, 7, 16
9. Do you want to do another sorting(yes/no)  :  no
10. Program Finished.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop, and with five lines solve the exercise:

```
continue_prog = True
while continue_prog:
    num_list = input("Enter three integers separated by commas: ").replace(' ','').split(',')
    print(f"The ascending order is: {sorted(num_list, key=int)}")
    # Exits unless the answer is yes/Yes/YES
    continue_prog= input("Do you want to do another sorting(yes/no)? ").lower().replace(' ','') == 'yes'
```

Comment: Downvoted because why answer this guy's homework questions.. it isn't helping anyone else who comes to StackOverflow and it isn't helping the original poster either.

Answer (score -1):

input as

```
integers = raw_input().split(',').tolist()
 if(integers[-1] == "no"):
    exit()
```

I hope this works